# SquareView does not layout it's children correctly

Tags: android, layout

I've a simply layout like following for a custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/someInnerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_arrow"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this function in my custom view:

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (mForceSquareLayout) {
        int w = getMeasuredWidth();
        int h = getMeasuredHeight();
        if (w != h) {
            int size = Math.min(w, h);
            setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
        }
    }
}
```

Any my layout looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="?toolbar_view_theme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="16dp" />

        <CustomView
            android:id="@+id/wheel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:square_layout="true"
            app:arrow_image="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_white_24dp"
            app:background_color="?colorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

The problem is, that if the square logic does resize the view (which it does in landscape mode), my custom views child `iv_arrow` is not shown anymore. It looks like my square logic does not relayout the children. Any ideas how to solve this?

I tried `requestLayout` on the view and on the child with no success...

Comment: `iv_arrow` does not appear to be a child of your custom view in either provided example?

Comment: Sorry, made a small mistake. The first layout is my custom view I'm talking about here... Corrected this